# Correct way to load nodes lazily in Neo4J with the Java API

Tags: java, neo4j

I just want to make sure I don't load in memory all the nodes of the db, only those called with nodes.next() in the iterator. This is what I have:

```
    try (Transaction tx = graphDB.beginTx()) {
        Node node = graphDB.getNodeById(1);
        ResourceIterator<Node> nodes = graphDB.traversalDescription().evaluator(Evaluators.all()).traverse(node).nodes().iterator();

        while (nodes.hasNext()) {
            Node node = nodes.next();
            // do stuff with the node...

       }
   }
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's correct.

Only the nodes that are pulled by nodes.next() are loaded.

During iteration it pulls the data as needed to fullfill the Iterator.